# Reference request for computing gluon scattering amplitudes in $\mathcal{N} = 4$ SYM in the planar limit

Tags: resource-recommendations, scattering, supersymmetry, yang-mills, s-matrix-theory

Could someone please provide me some reference(s), preferably that I can find online for free (arXiv for example or other), which would explain in some detail how to calculate gluon scattering amplitudes in $\mathcal{N} = 4$ SYM in the planar limit please? I am a mathematician, not a physicist, though I am also not a complete beginner in Physics either (I guess I am "intermediate" in Physics). I don't require that it be written for mathematicians, but that it explain in some detail how to calculate such scattering amplitudes please. If the reference contains a few worked out examples, then that would be great.

My motivation comes from a completely different problem, the Atiyah problem on configurations of points. I am trying to find a physical interpretation for the Atiyah-Sutcliffe determinant. Indeed, I know how to express it in terms of products of $2$ by $2$ determinants of Weyl spinors and, from what I know, these are precisely the type of expressions occuring in formulas for the scattering amplitudes above. I am only providing my motivation to explain why I am personally interested in such scattering amplitudes, and the type of formulas I am interested in. Of course, the references I am asking for will most probably not mention this problem at all.

Edit: I think the article "Scattering Amplitudes and the Positive Grassmannian" by N. Arkani-Hameda, J. Bourjailyb, F. Cachazoc, A. Goncharovd, A. Postnikove, and J. Trnkaa,f is a great reference (it is [[hep-th] arXiv:1212.5605v2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.5605)). There are, here and there, some things I am not familiar with, but I am getting by, for now. For instance, for an introduction to supersymmetry, I found the book [SUPERSPACE](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0108200), by S. James Gates, Jr., Marcus T. Grisaru, Martin Roček and Warren Siegel really helpful, particularly chap. 2 (a toy superspace), which gives the flavor of what is going on in more complicated examples. For example, there is a formula for a delta function with respect to integrating over Grassmann variables which seems to be implicitly used in the article above on scattering amplitudes and the positive Grassmannian. There is a simpler version of that formula in the Superspace book, which gave me the hint. I leave these 2 references here, as they may be helpful to someone else trying to learn related Physics on their own (not an easy task).